# How to git diff remote branches and specify the repository at the same time?

Tags: windows, git, bitbucket

I have a `develop` branch and a `master` branch.  I want to get the differences between the two on a box where I've never cloned any repos.  So I tried:

```
git diff --no-index remotes/origin/master remotes/origin/develop
```

It tells me `error: Could not access 'remotes/origin/master'`, which is fair enough since it doesn't know what repo to get it from.

So how do I tell git the location of the repository, so that I could get the diff?

Answer (score 2):

That's not the way to do it. Try this:

```
git diff origin/master origin/develop
```

Comment: But I still have to tell git which repo to connect to.  How do I do that?  This is happening on a box that's been created on the fly.

Comment: No connection whatsoever. Git diff will work on whatever information it holds about the remotes at the time. And you provide remote/branch-name. So it could be (just making stuff up) `git diff remote1/branchA remote2/branchB`

Comment: I guess your question is not really about diff but about remotes. Add the two remotes and run `git fetch --all`, then try diffing.

Comment: If there's no clone, though, then there are no defined remotes.

Comment: That's basically the question.  I want to do a server side diff without fetching both repositories down to the box (cause they are multi-GB).

Comment: Right..... so you add them with `git remote add remote-name remote-url`. one at a time.

Comment: So then git doesn't support server-side diffing?  I was under impression that it did.

Comment: Yeah.. a totally different question from what's specified. Perhaps you could try doing `git fetch --shallow` so that you don't pull everything from the repos?

Comment: Server side diffing? Doesn't ring a bell in my mind. One of the advantages of using git is that operations are performed locally.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the `remotes`.
The remotes is the folder where git store the branch files.

In git branches are simply files with a given SHA-1 which are stored under inside the remotes folder

[image]

---

In order to compare branches, you don`t need to use the`remotes`

```
# Using the diff command
git diff origin/<branch_name> origin/<branch name>

# Using the log command
git log ^origin/<branch_name> origin/<branch name>
git log origin/<branch_name> ^origin/<branch name>
```